# intellij ESlint + JavaScript Standard Style + Code Style Scheme none consistent

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, react-native, coding-style, code-standards

I have done the following:

1. Installed [JavaScript Standard Style](https://github.com/standard/standard) globally.
2. Set the standard in the IntelliJ ESLint settings.
3. Set the JavaScript code style as **Set From-->Predefined Style-->JavaScript Standard Style**.

When start coding (for example React Native), there is inconsistency between the code style loaded in ESlint and the Code Style used in IntelliJ, for example:

> a space is required before closing bracket react/jsx-tag-spacing

When using IntelliJ auto format this hasn't been solved.

Any ideas how to fix this inconsistency?

- IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2017.2.4
- Latest JavaScript code style.

Answer (score 0):

Please try enabling **Spaces/In empty tag** in **Settings | Editor | Code Style | HTML | Other**

Comment: The "space is required" issue is not the only one I get, I'm looking for a robust way of doing this, so both settings will be consistent with each other.